# fmt.Scan разделяет аргументы

Tags: golang, split

У меня есть код, который работает корректно, но не так как бы я хотел, как решить проблему я не знаю.

```
    var s string
    fmt.Scan(&s)

    if s == "hello world" {
        fmt.Println("HELLO")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Unexcepted", string(s))
    }
```

Выводит:

```
Unexcepted hello
Unexcepted world
```

Тоесть оно как бы разделяет аргументы по пробелу, но мне это не нужно, нужно чтоб всё было вместе. Как это сделать?

Comment: `fmt.Println("Unexcepted", string(s))` -> `fmt.Println("Unexcepted" + s)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
fmt.Println("Unexcepted", string(s))
```

так ты перечисляешь аргументы

```
 fmt.Printf("Unexcepted%s", string(s))
```

будет выводить

```
Unexceptedhello
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает по документации:

> Scan scans text read from standard input, storing successive *space-separated* values into successive arguments.

Если вы хотите читать поток построчно, используйте [буферизованный сканер](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner).